# entry_points path changed in development mode install

Tags: python, installation, setuptools, setup.py

My console_scripts/entry_points are not working in "develop" mode install and produce a traceback saying ImportError cannot load the module containing the entry points. Need help understanding how entry_points figure out which module to load and what paths to setup and stuff. Help fixing my error.

I have a setup.py script that has some entry points as follows

```
entry_points = {'console_scripts':[
    'pyjampiler=pyjs.pyjampiler:Builder',
    'pyjscompile=pyjs.translator:main',
    'pyjsbuild=pyjs.browser:build_script',
]}
```

my code is organized as

```
workspace/
    setup.py
    pyjs/
        src/
            pyjs/
                browser.py
```

My setup.py makes use of packages and package_dir arguments to setup() in setup.py to make sure the pyjs package gets picked up from pyjs/src/pyjs and so a regular install produces the following console scripts containing the following and it runs fine. it is able to load the module and call the entry point fine.

sys.exit(
   load_entry_point('pyjs==0.8.1', 'console_scripts', 'pyjsbuild')()
)

But when I install and run it in development as "python setup.py develop", the install goes fine and I see the egg.lnk files getting created. but executing the console script causes the following errors

```
localhost:pyjs sarvi$ lpython/bin/pyjsbuild 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lpython/bin/pyjsbuild", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pyjs==0.8.1', 'console_scripts', 'pyjsbuild')()
  File "/Users/sarvi/Workspace/pyjs/lpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 318, in load_entry_point
  File "/Users/sarvi/Workspace/pyjs/lpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2221, in load_entry_point
  File "/Users/sarvi/Workspace/pyjs/lpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
ImportError: No module named browser
```

I suspect it has something to do with sys.path and the directory structure in the development sources. How can I get this to work in "develop" mode install?